# How to access elements outside of root during react testing?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

So I have an index.html file like this where there is a span outside of root div.

```
// index.html

<div id="root" class="root-container">
    <div class="splash-holder">
        <div class="triangle-holder">
            <div class="triangle four"></div>
            <div class="triangle five"></div>
            <div class="triangle six"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<span class="hidden-tag" id="hidden-span"></span>
```

and my Index.js file looks like this, where you can see main app is being rendered inside root-container.

```
// index.js

const MainApp = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Foo />
    </Provider>
);

ReactDOM.render(<MainApp/>, document.querySelector('.root-container'));
```

and my Foo component file is like the following.

```
// Foo.js

const Foo = () => {
    const ele = document.getElementById('hidden-span');
    ele.innerHTML = 'dsaas';
}
```

Though this works fine in the actual app but when I try to render component using react testing library. eg.

```
// Foo.test.js

import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Foo from ./components;

render(<Foo />);
```

I get the error that cannot find innerHTML of null. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: If there's no apparent reason to keep HTML in index.html, you can move it to React components. But if you want to keep HTML in index.html, then you have to create your custom render for tests as described here: https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#custom-render

Comment: Yes, I was going to ask the same, can't you create that div some other way? maybe via a react portal?

Comment: @Max Thankyou for your response, I completely agree with you that HTML shouldn't be in index.html but I am working on someone else's code and I am not supposed to change it. I agree with your proposed solution of custom render, and thats what I was also thinking. For now I have added following code in setupTests file
```
const element = global.document.createElement('span');
    element.setAttribute('id', 'hidden-span');
    global.document.body.append(element);
```
But I am confused if this is better or custom render or there is some other more elegant solution?

Comment: "but I am working on someone else's code and I am not supposed to change it." I felt that. 
Accessing elements that shouldn't be there when testing a component in isolation might be difficult. Do you think you could set up your `const ele` as state with a dummy default, and then set it from inside a useEffect hook instead? That would prevent the DOM access on every single re-render as well.

Comment: @IbrahimNoor I suggest using a custom renderer, it's way more flexible and you won't have to create the element manually with global.document

Answer (score 0):

#### Answering question in title

I was able to access element outside root only by **getByTestId** query.

https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/